# Javascript/SparkAR — How to transform scale smoothly using Javascript in SparkAR?

Tags: javascript, animation, transformation, spark-ar-studio

I am trying to transform the scale of a plane smoothly without success. I am trying to avoid the pop from one random integer to another. The aim is to make this place scale to the new value in a smooth way.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Pseudo-code

- Set a random value
- Transform the current scale to the new scale in a smooth way
- Do it five times
- Reset to the original value
- Rinse and repeat

Code

```
  const [plane] = await Promise.all([Scene.root.findFirst('plane0')]);

  const timeInMilliseconds = 1000;
  const planeTransform = plane.transform;
  const planeWidth = planeTransform.scaleX.pinLastValue();
  var numTransform = 0;

  function randomScale() {
    const randomNum = Random.random();

    if (numTransform < 5) {
      planeTransform.scaleX = Reactive.mul(randomNum, 2);
      Diagnostics.log('Function random');
    } else {
      numTransform = 0;
      planeTransform.scaleX = Reactive.mul(planeWidth, 1);
      Diagnostics.log('Function random reset');
    }
  }

  const intervalTimer = Time.setInterval(
    () => randomScale(numTransform++),
    timeInMilliseconds
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is to:

1. add nullObject and apply random scale values to it
2. bind planeTransform scale to nullObject with expSmooth()

I know this is seems like a silly method, but this is the result of Reactive-ness of the engine.
This will not work properly for rotations!